# How to get file key out of an SNS connected to S3 Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have two different profiles on AWS. The s3 bucket and SNS are in profile A and my lambda function is in profile B. When a new file is added to the s3 bucket, SNS triggers the lambda function.

The lambda function then supposed to access the new file and process it using pandas. Here is what I'm doing now;

```
    sts_connection = boto3.client('sts')
acct_b = sts_connection.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::**************:role/AllowS3AccessFromAccountB",
    RoleSessionName="cross_acct_lambda"
)

ACCESS_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
SECRET_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
SESSION_TOKEN = acct_b['Credentials']['SessionToken']

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN)

path = get_file_path(event)
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='my-bucket-name', Key=path)
csv_string = io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read())

# Read a csv file and turn it into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_json(csv_string, delimiter=';', engine ='c', encoding= 'unicode_escape')

def get_file_path(event_body):
"""Function to get manifest path anc check if it is manifest"""
try:
    # Get message for first SNS record
    sns_message = json.loads(event_body["Records"][0]["Sns"]["Message"])
    path = sns_message["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
except TypeError as ex:
    logging.error("Unable to parse event: " + str(event_body))
    raise ex
return path
```

Everything works fine until the s3.get_object() part. I'm getting the following error;

```
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

Maybe I'm reading the file key in the wrong way?

Edit:
Here is what path looks like when I debugged it.

```
svv/sensor%3D11219V22151/year%3D2020/month%3D03/day%3D02/test.csv
```

And the s3 file structure is like this;

```
sensor-data/sensor=*******/year=2020/month=03/day=02
```

Seems like I need to use a regex for the equal signs. But there should be a more generic solution.

Comment: You need to show the the code for the `get_file_path` function. That's where the key is being extracted from the event, which is the focus of your entire question, so without that code your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Just added it. Thanks for the warning. I missed that. @MarkB

Comment: why not get the bucket and the key info from the SNS message?  perhaps the hard coded bucket does not match the bucket from the message?  have you debugged the value of `path` and make sure that the file exists in the bucket?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I debugged the path and added the output to the question. It's actually better to use the bucket name from SNS message as you mentioned but I already get the file key from the message. @JDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a snippet I have in some Lambda code that is *directly* triggered by Amazon S3 (not via Amazon SNS):

```py
import urllib

key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
```

You could try the similar parsing to see if it corrects the Key.